# Не меняется размер размер кнопок в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Код:

```
save = tk.Button(root, text='Save', relief="flat", bg='#8DFF61', width=10, height=1)
save.pack(side='left', pady=40, anchor='s', expand=1)
save.config(command=save_p)

exit = tk.Button(root, text='Close', relief="flat", bg='#B0B0B0', width=10, height=1)
exit.pack(side='right', pady=40, anchor='s', expand=1)
exit.config(command=close)
```

Причём до этого у меня был другой шрифт в кнопках и размер кнопок менялся в зависимости от размера шрифта но после удаления шрифта размер не меняется. До удаления шрифта код выглядел так:

```
helv36 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=10)

save = tk.Button(root, text='Save', relief="flat", bg='#8DFF61', font=helv36)
save.pack(side='left', pady=40, anchor='s', expand=1)
save.config(width=10, height=50, command=save_p)

exit = tk.Button(root, text='Close', relief="flat", bg='#B0B0B0', font=helv36)
exit.pack(side='right', pady=40, anchor='s', expand=1)
exit.config(width=10, height=50, command=close)
```

Менять размер кнопок в конфиге уже пробовал

Comment: я сейчас заметил что если удалить `pady=40` то размер меняется, но что делать если мне нужен отступ и размер кнопок?

Comment: Как именно должен меняться размер в зависимости от размера шрифта, если шрифт вы не меняете?

Comment: нет, мне нужно что бы я мог задать размер, то есть высоту и ширину кнопки, а шрифт должен настраиваться отдельно

Comment: Я протестировал, изменение width и height вполне успешно изменяет размеры кнопок: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7qI5.png

Comment: @insolor я выяснил что размер зависит от `pady`, чем меньше тем больше кнопка, можно ли это как то поправить?

Comment: Вроде бы pady никак не влияет, что с pady, что без него одинаковый размер у кнопок: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqxBy.png

Comment: Надо изменить config на configure

Comment: так я сделал калькулятор